# Trouble installing chatterbot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pip, bots

i'm installing Chatterbot cause i'll use it on a project but when I try to install then there's an error:

```
pip install ./ChatterBot
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Processing ./ChatterBot
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-xd5wZH/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        platform.python_version()
    Exception: You are tying to install ChatterBot on Python version 2.7.16.
    Please install ChatterBot in Python 3 instead.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-xd5wZH/
```

I'm using a rasPi w/ raspbian, this is the last apt that I need to install to do my project.

Also, I already did

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Not 100%, but it looks as if the [builds from piwheels for Chatterbot](https://www.piwheels.org/project/ChatterBot/) are all Python 3.4+. You may want to try downloading and installing the wheels available from that link manually instead.

Comment: So, I need to install using pip3 install piwheels? Cause I realised that I was doing just pip install instead of pip3 install :P

Comment: Lol! Yep, you should probably give that a try. =)

Comment: I tried aaand it's returning the same prob

Answer (score 0):

```
python3.10 -m pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

Try this, it worked for me. Use the python version you have.